# Pandas: clean & convert DataFrame to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing strings, as read from a sloppy csv:

```
id  Total           B                  C        ...                                        
0   56 974          20 739             34 482   
1   29 479          10 253             16 704   
2   86 961          29 837             43 593   
3   52 687          22 921             28 299   
4   23 794           7 646             15 600
```

What I want to do: convert every cell in the frame into a number. It should be ignoring whitespaces, but put NaN where the cell contains something really strange.
I probably know how to do it using terribly unperformant manual looping and replacing values, but was wondering if there's a nice and clean why to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with regex separator `\s{2,}` - 2 or more whitespaces and parameter `thousands`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""id  Total           B                  C                                           
0   56 974          20 739             34 482   
1   29 479          10 253             16 704   
2   86 961          29 837             43 593   
3   52 687          22 921             28 299   
4   23 794           7 646             15 600   """
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', thousands=' ')

print (df)
   id  Total      B      C
0   0  56974  20739  34482
1   1  29479  10253  16704
2   2  86961  29837  43593
3   3  52687  22921  28299
4   4  23794   7646  15600

print (df.dtypes)
id       int64
Total    int64
B        int64
C        int64
dtype: object
```

And then if necessary `apply` function [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - it replace non numeric to `NaN`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```